# How do I hide my <div> element by default when pulling up my website?

Tags: html

so I tried to change the "myInfo.style.display = 'block'" to document.getElementById('demo').style.display = 'none' and it didn't work, so im struggling to figure out how to hide the  by default so that when I click the button it then displays it.

here's the code

```
      <center><p><button onclick="myFunction()" id="button">Show More</button></center></p><br>

<script>
  function myFunction() {
    var myInfo = document.getElementById('demo');

    var displaySetting = myInfo.style.display;

    var clockButton = document.getElementById('button');

    if (displaySetting == 'block') {
      myInfo.style.display = 'none';
      clockButton.innerHTML = 'Show Info';
    }
    else {
      myInfo.style.display = 'block';
      clockButton.innerHTML = 'Hide Info';
    }
  }
</script>
     <div id="demo"><font color="black"><b>Fav Color:</b> Orange/Purple<br><b>Hobbies:</b> Coding, Video games, Hanging out with friends, Drifting<br><b>Fav Song:</b> Homocide - Logic (ft. Eminem)<br><b>Fav Animal:</b> Cat<br><b>Fav Food:</b> Pulled Pork Sandwich</font></div>
```

Comment: You can just add a style to the div: `<div id="demo" style="display: none;">...</div>`

Comment: Right but I’m trying to use the button element to hide and show the <div> which is why I’m a little confused

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Sumner Evans](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2319844/sumner-evans) said in their comment, just add

```
style="display: none"
```

to your div tag.
It will be hidden by default and your button will work.  You can test it here: https://jsfiddle.net/0v3fzo97/